# Where to add Google analytics code to a php website

Tags: google-analytics

When adding Google analytics code to a php website do I add the code to only the index page, every page created or only the front facing pages in the customer journey?
What is the best practice?
Thank you for any responses in advance.

Answer (score 7):

All the pages you want analytics on, add the code on the front facing pages.
Best practice will be to create a file "analytics.php" and paste the code there, and add

`<?php include_once("analytics.php"); ?>`

To all the front facing pages

Comment: Could "analytics.txt" be more efficient than "analytics.php"?

Answer (score 3):

**In Your Google Analytics Account:**

*Go to Home - > Admin -> Under Property click on Tracking Info ->*

I usually put mine in the sub directory of partials/header.php in my server so it goes into every page that I create in the main directory.

This was taken from Google Analytics in 03/2014 (it might change)

**PHP Implementation** (optional)

Create a PHP file named "analyticstracking.php" with the code above and include it on each PHP template page. Then, add the following line to each template page immediately after the opening  tag:

```
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
```

**Dynamic Content Implementation** (optional)

Use a common include or template to paste the code above instead of manually adding it to every page.
WAP site - for older feature phonesoptional

If you have a site built for older feature phones with no JavaScript support, or if you cannot use JavaScript for some other reason, you can download the server-side code libraries from [here.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites)

Answer (score 1):

Add the code on every page you want to track (typically every page within your web site). If this is a dynamically (via PHP) generated website you most likely have template files or common header/footer files (at least you should have) so you can insert your code there, or create a separate file with the analytics code and use an include (this is even mentioned n the analytics interface, at the page that let's you fetch the GA code).

Answer (score 0):

you can put same code in header.php where you can initialize ga(setting account api key etc..) .and use it throughout the website.