# Adding Google Analytics code to PHP file not working

Tags: php, redirect, google-analytics, php-include

I know this question was asked before multiple times but none of these solutions: ([solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201082/where-to-add-google-analytics-code-to-a-php-website), [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621482/how-to-add-google-analytics-code-to-php-pages-per-googles-instruction), [solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107699/adding-google-analytics-to-php-website)) has worked for me. This is my first time dealing with PHP code and I'm trying to add Google Analytics tracking to my `index.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php
    include('someOtherFile.php'); 

    // Redirect to example.com
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    die();
?>
```

I created the `analyticstracking.php` like instructed by Google, placed it in the same folder as my `index.php` file and added the following row to my code like this:

```
<?php
    include('someOtherFile.php'); 
    include('analyticstracking.php');

    // Redirect to example.com
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    die();
?>
```

The result was that the redirect to example.com stopped working and analytics didn't work as well.

I then tried:

```
<?php include('analyticstracking.php'); ?>
<?php
    include('someOtherFile.php'); 

    // Redirect to example.com
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    die();
?>
```

Which made analytics work but the redirect didn't.

And this version:

```
<?php
    include('someOtherFile.php'); 

    // Redirect to example.com
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    die();
?>
<?php include('analyticstracking.php'); ?>
```

Which made the redirect work but analytics didn't.

So I finnaly tried a diffrent approach and tried this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php include('analyticstracking.php'); ?>
    <?php
        include('someOtherFile.php'); 

        // Redirect to example.com
        header("Location: http://www.example.com");
        die();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Which acted exactly the same as not using the `<html>` tags (first php tag wins).

Also tried `include_once` as well as adding the script to the php file itself. nothing worked. Always the first piece of code wins.

So what am I missing here? What is the right way to make my redirect work together with the google analytics include?

Comment: What's inside `analyticstracking.php`?

Comment: It will just not work that way. Google Analytics is a client side tracking and it depends upon the fact, that the page delivered by your server is rendered and JavaScript code is executed by the clients browser. If you order the client to perform a redirect, via setting the appropriate header, this is not the case - so no tracking is performed.

Doing it the other way round will also not work. You cannot set the header after your script generated some output - like the Analytics tracking code.

Comment: @AlessandroNiciforo, This is the code: `<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-0000000-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>`

Comment: @DerVO , So is there anything I can do in order to accomplish a redirect and Google analytics tracking?

Comment: @DMEN In a strict interpretation, the answer would be no. But of course there are options. You can try to track the redirects on your target page. Your page will be the referer here. You also can append a parameter to the redirect url (maybe a campaign) and track that. Our you can redirect the user with a meta oder JavaScript redirect instead of a header (although I do not recommend that).

Comment: @DerVO Unfortunately, the page I'm redirecting to isn't under my control. I changed it to an html page and added `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com">` line in the `<head>` section, right after the Google Analytics' script. It's working now but a tiny bit slower... are there any down sides to what I did?

Comment: @DMEM: They are some downsides (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks) - but I think they are acceptable in your case.

Comment: @DerVO, Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the analytics code in analyticstracking.php

So you're code will be:

**analyticstracking.php**

```
<?php
echo "
<script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-0000000-1', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>
";
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include_once("analyticstracking.php");
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
die();
?>
```

Tested and it works for me. :)